# What to do with a coding challenge question where the problem statement is in an external link/page?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I was browsing the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag and came across this post: [Wrong answer on Codechef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322685/wrong-answer-on-codechef).

The post is about a coding challenge from CodeChef. I've read that questions from coding challenge sites are generally [frowned upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329741/2745495) but it's best to [treat it like any other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342284/2745495).

Given that, my main concern I'm having with the post is that the problem statement ***isn't*** part of the post itself. It's just a link to an external page. I don't know much about CodeChef, but if that page changes or is removed, then this SO post becomes useless to future readers.

What is the correct action here?

1. Flag as off-topic because:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to **reproduce it in the question itself**.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example.

2. Flag as *unclear what you're asking*.
3. Suggest an edit to copy the entire problem into the post itself.
   (This requires time and effort, and it feels like plagiarism.)
4. Leave a comment to the user to improve his own question.
   (Though this does not guarantee the post will be fixed.)
5. Just let it be.

I'm inclined to do **1** and **4**.
I am just not sure if there's a better action.

Comment: 1 or 2 would be ok IMHO. You can do 3, but make it very clear in your summary that's what you're doing, or it will be rejected.  4 is hit or miss, and I think would make more sense if coupled with another action

Comment: Just downvote and ask the user to move the code into the question and keep the link for reference. Update the downvote when the user edits the question.

Comment: Debugging questions must be stand-alone. If they can't make it stand-alone, we can't help debug and such a question should be closed.